# How to put a small custom toolbar above the Keyboard that moves up and down with it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikit, keyboard

How to put a small custom toolbar above the Keyboard that moves up and down with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Keyboard Accessory View. [Here is a sample project](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html)